# disabled=false does not work in typescript 2.1

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am trying to disable a field by getting element ID in typescript 2.1. I found this below syntax for typescript 1.5. But it does not work in 2.1. Can anybody help.

( document.getElementById('BenchForcastId_'+valueID)).disabled = false;

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you mean by 'does not work' the fact that compiler will give you an error saying:

> Property 'disabled' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Then it is exactly what it says. In order to fix this you can cast it to the type that does have disabled property, for example:

```
(document.getElementById('BenchForcastId_'+valueID) as HTMLButtonElement).disabled = false;
```

If you do not know the type (or there can be many different ones) but know for sure that it has disabled property you can cast to any:

```
(document.getElementById('BenchForcastId_'+valueID) as any).disabled = false;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. It is not throwing error also. But none of the above code helped me.

Comment: Can you please clarify what is the problem you are getting?

Comment: I use Dev Extreme framework for my form fields. I have a dx-date-box widget with the attribute [disabled]="true". When i tried to implement your code in my angular function, it did not change the attribute value also it did not throw an error.

Comment: Try to open your page in chrome dev tools and see that there is actually a dom element with 'BenchForcastId_'+valueID identifier. You are using pure javascript here - if it does not work - it means there is no element with such id in the document.

Comment: You are correct. Dev Extreme date-box has different ID. It works now. Thank you.